# Escape a variable in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to pass in a variable as an index to set an active row with a little bit of jquery. I have my variable storing correctly but cannot seem to get jquery to accept the variable in an argument.

Here's what I've got:

```
$(this).find("td:eq('storeDex')").addClass("activeRow");
```

storeDex is the variable, If I drop a normal number there it seems to work fine, I'm thinking maybe I need to escape the vaiable some how but I cannot seem to figure out how to do it. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: OK, I finally got my snippet working in my answer below. Basically like you said, you have to escape the variable, but it's not called escaping, it would actually be concatenation of the jQuery selector string to include your variable as a literal in the string.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the jQuery :eq selector documentation http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/

```
$( "td:eq( 2 )" ).css( "color", "red" );
```

So I would leave out the single quotes in your example, and the result would look like this:

```
$(this).find("td:eq(" + storeDex + ")").addClass("activeRow");
```

## Snippet example

```js
var storeDex = 2;
$(function () {
    $("td:eq(" + storeDex + ")").addClass("activeRow");
});
```

```css
.activeRow {
  background-color:yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Table cell 1</td>
    <td>Table cell 2</td>
    <td>Table cell 3</td>
    <td>Table cell 4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to terminate your string, append the variable and finish your jquery selector with another string.

```
$(this).find("td:eq('" + storeDex + "')").addClass("activeRow");
```